# PHP5.5 or PHP5.6 Availability for CentOS 7

Tags: centos, software-installation, php5

Is php5.5 or php5.6 Available for CentOS 7?

Comment: did my answer helped you to get php5.6 ?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, it is available for CentOS 7. You just have to add "Webtatic EL yum repository" information corresponding to your CentOS/RHEL version to yum, like :

```
rpm -Uvh https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
rpm -Uvh https://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el7/webtatic-release.rpm
```

You can install php now, using :

```
yum install php56w php56w-opcache
```

Once completed, check php version by using command,

```
php -v
```

**Update**

as suggested by @jsbillings, Webtatic is listed as one of the 'known problem' repos on the [CentOS Wiki](https://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories). You can use *IUS* or *SCL* from [CentOS Wiki](https://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories) instead of Webtatic.

Comment: So I did what you suggested and it is still showing PHP 5.4.16 after I ran php -v

Comment: @TwitchedOut did you get any error while performing any steps which I mentioned ?

Comment: Webtatic is listed as one of the 'known problem' repos on the [CentOS Wiki](https://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories).  Better to suggest IUS or SCL.

Comment: @jsbillings ah, you are right. thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @TwitchedOut see my updates and try again with new repos.

Answer (score 1):

Red Hat has been working on a set of repositories called Software Collections (SCL).  CentOS 7 includes a similar set of repositories which make it easier to install PHP 5.6, 7.1, and other things not available in the base repositories.  I also recommend using EPEL and if you haven't changed defaults, it's as easy as:

```
yum install epel-release
yum install centos-release-scl
```

Now you should have access to all of the EPEL and SCL packages.  To install PHP 7.1, you can simply

```
yum install rh-php71
```

It will add the packages to `/opt/rh/rh-php71/root/*`, but the php.ini configuration will reside in `/etc/opt/rh/rh-php71/`.  To make the newly installed version of PHP the default PHP used from the command line, you can add to a file in `/etc/profile.d/` :

```
printf '#!/bin/bash\nsource scl_source enable rh-php71\n' > /etc/profile.d/php71.sh ; chmod ugo+r /etc/profile.d/php71.sh
```

The process is similar for PHP 5.6.  All of the other pre-built packages for PHP 7.1 can be found with:

```
yum search php71
```

More information about the EPEL and SCL repositories can be found here:

https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL

https://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/SCL